# Is ramification of number fields first order?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, nt.number-theory

Fix a prime number $p$. Is there a first order sentence $\phi_p$ in the language of fields such that $\phi_p$ holds in a number field $K$ if and only if the prime $p$ is unramified in the field extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more explanation for those of us who are not number-theory experts?

Comment: Hi Joel. There are many intuitions about what ramification means, but here is the easiest definition. Let $O_K$ be the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $K$. Then, since $O_K$ is a Dedekind domain, you can write $pO_K$ as a product $\mathfrak{p}_1^{e_1}...\mathfrak{p_n}^{e_n}$ where the $\mathfrak{p_i}$'s are different prime ideals of $O_K$. The prime $p$ is said to be unramified if $e_1=...=e_n=1$ (i.e. if no prime ideal appears more than once in the decomposition of $pO_K$). The most intuitive kind of ramification is by taking roots of $p$ (e.g. $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ ramifies at $2$), but

Comment: ramification can appear in more subtle ways, like this: the prime $2$ ramifies in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

Comment: (in scheme theory, this number-theoretic notion of ramification becomes the same as the geometric notion of ramification of maps between varieties.)

Comment: I am far from an expert in logic, but my gut feeling is that the algorithm on p.28 of the pdf here http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/math5230f08/schoof.pdf could yield a first order statement because $p$ ramifies in $K$ if and only if $p$ divides the discriminant of $\mathcal O_K$ as a $\mathbb Z$-algebra.

Answer (score 6):

I THINK, the answer is YES by a paper of [Robert Rumely](http://www.math.uga.edu/~rr/):

[Undecidability and definability of the theory of global fields](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDkQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uga.edu%2F~rr%2FTheoryGlobalFields.pdf&ei=0cRoT4mkGc_pgQff8tHbCQ&usg=AFQjCNHaN-u3tRcdJFy9My8Utq3wPKyZ1Q&sig2=zuyr1_L10dDbS49nDthfBw), 1980,

where he showed that "a great variety of number-theoretic objects, from rings of integers and valuations, to zeta-functions and adele rings" are definable. Many of them are actually uniformally definable.

For the ramification issue, see the bottom of Page 210.